# Avoiding Helmholtz decomposition

Tags: electromagnetism

When potentials are introduced in electrodynamics, is it possible to avoid the explicit application of the Helmholtz (decomposition) theorem? For example, for electrostatics, it is easy to give a reasoning why the electric field can be described as a gradient of a scalar field. Because, the static electric field is conservative, hence, a potential function can be defined. However, how to give a justification that the B field can be written as a curl of the "vectorpotential", if we don't want to refer to the Helmholtz theorem?

Answer (score 2):

The existance of the vector field is the [Poincare lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms#Application_in_electrodynamics).

Answer (score 0):

In physics it is customary to just assume the useful object exists (here, vector potential), and worry about that existence later only when problems are encountered.

In usual expositions of EM theory it is just assumed that any field $\mathbf B$ obeying the equation

$$
\nabla \cdot \mathbf B = 0 ~~~(everywhere)
$$
has a solution of the form
$$
\mathbf B = \nabla \times \mathbf A
$$

for *some* field $\mathbf A$.

A mathematical proof is not an easy topic and I can't give you one. But you will find that there have to be some assumptions(restrictions) on the field $\mathbf B$, such as being smooth enough. If the magnetic field has a jump at some point or set of points such as curved line or a surface (1D wire, 2D current sheet), which is a common situation in textbook EM theory, you'll find that value of magnetic field at those points (either undefined or discontinuous isolated value) can't be expressed as
$$
\mathbf B = \nabla \times \mathbf A
$$
for any function $\mathbf A$. Similarly for electric field acting on charge distributed on a charged 2D sphere - it cannot be expressed as $-\nabla \varphi$ for any function $\varphi$.

So the rule of thumb is, potentials exists for smooth distributions of matter, there are mathematical theorems such the Helmholtz decomposition one and others, but if there are discontinuities in charge or current distributions, the assumptions are not met and the usual formulae giving fields as derivatives of potentials fail.

Answer (score 0):

1. The Ampere law is a similar problem:
   $$
   div B =0, $$
   $$
   rot B = \mu j.
   $$
   Physical realism tells us that this problem has a mathematical solution.
2. If we go back to the vectorpotential, we suppose that there exists $A$ that
   $$
   div A =0, $$
   $$
   rot A = B.
   $$
   Since (1) is solvable for a wide range of $j$, (2) should also be solvable for a wide range of $B$. Now, we have proved the existence and uniqueness of the vectorpotential with the Coulomb gauge. If $div A$ is non-zero, we can add a gradient field to $A$.

3. However, we should consider the solvability of (1). It should be solvable if $j$ somehow disappears at infinity. The same should be applied to problem (2). The $B$ field should tend to zero at infinity. However, this issue needs clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps, looking at Maxwell's equations:

1. since a divergence-free field can be written as the curl of a vector field:

   $\quad 0 =\nabla \cdot \mathbf{b}$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \ \rightarrow\qquad$$\mathbf{b} = \nabla \times \mathbf{a}$;
2. since curl-free field can be written as a gradient of a scalar field:

   $\quad \mathbf{0} = \nabla \times \mathbf{e} + \partial_t \mathbf{b} = \nabla \times \left( \mathbf{e} + \partial_t \mathbf{a} \right)$ $\qquad \rightarrow \qquad$$\mathbf{e} + \partial_t \mathbf{a} = - \nabla \varphi$.

The definition of the fields $\mathbf{a}$, $\varphi$ has some arbitrariness, since:

- the vector potential is defined up to a gradient, $\mathbf{a} \rightarrow \mathbf{a} + \nabla \eta$, since $\nabla \times \nabla \eta = \mathbf{0}$;
- the potential field is defined up to a function of time only $\phi \rightarrow \phi + f(t)$, since $\nabla f(t) = 0$.

The definition of a gauge condition follows to completely determine the potentials, usually **Lorentz condition** (that is Lorentz invariant, for relativity),

$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{a} + \dfrac{1}{c^2} \partial_t \varphi = 0$.